My house has Cat 5e Ethernet cables but no jacks - how do I figure out where these cables lead?
We're in a decade-old house that didn't have any coaxial or fiber Internet until just this week. Last night while looking inside the cabinet where the house's coax network feeds into, I noticed there were Cat 5e cables just hanging there, ends capped with wire nuts.
However, insofar as I have been able to search, there are no Ethernet wall outlets anywhere in the house. The only telecom outlets I found are coax & phone, the latter of which I suspect use the thinner, white multipurpose telecom cables I also found.
There are plenty of tutorials online on locating cable, but they all assume you have the right outlets installed and just need to figure out which cable goes to which outlet.

No one in their right mind would 'cap' Ethernet cables with the connectors you posted.

That would actually be fairly common for people using the blue/white pair to run telephone wiring, joining up a bunch of Cat5e cables with phone on blue/white. Please [edit] the question to post pictures of your central wiring, and what's behind at least one of your phone jacks

@Ecnerwal wouldn’t it make more sense for them to use one wire for each phone jack, and maybe one color for telephone?

Please provide the requested pictures. I'm telling from decades of professional experience what is common to find. We can tell much more about what your setup is doing from the requested pictures, which will show the actual connections of the cabling and jacks. While your house might be unusual, it's more likely to be usual. In any case, you need to look.

Because phone wiring is pretty tolerant (compared to ethernet) the usual setup is (you hope, for a "might be turned into network" install) a big star with all the blue wires and all the white with blue wires joined to the telephone interface, and one cable per jack. If you're not lucky they may have run one cable to a jack, and then on to another jack, which works for phone, but not network. Unless they had two phone lines, it's usually just the blue/white pair. While it's not inconceivable to have all the phones segregated onto 2-pair phone cable, it does not track with wire nuts on the Cat5e

Still no pictures?

@Ecnerwal  no -- we determined that the phone jacks were, in fact, wired with Cat5e and have since repurposed the cat5e cables for internet use.

Open the phone jacks and look in the box to see what cable they actually use, (suspecting can be cured by 30 seconds of effort to open the wall plate and look) and if there are loose Cat5e cables in there if the Cat5e is not what's connected to the phone jacks.
If not there, look behind the plates with coax jacks for the unused Cat5e, and look behind "blank" junction box covers (being aware that some of those may have power wiring rather than communications wiring.)
Running phone on Cat5e is remarkably common. If done right (no daisy-chaining) it can easily be converted to Ethernet use. There's no practical reason other than use for phone to have wire-nuts on the Cat5e.
Even though I have a cable toner as part of my kit (no going out and spending money on it for a one-time job) it's not what I would reach for first here. They don't work terribly well through wall materials, for one thing. Cables are usually run to boxes or LV rings, with faceplates, and if you have telephone and coax wiring the odds of the network wiring sharing the same paths are huge. The wire nuts (lacking a picture yet) strongly suggest that the Cat5e is the phone wiring in most cases.

Buy an electrical tracer.  It puts a signal on the wire which you can then use to trace the wire in the wall using a wand.
